# How to extract the rows of cells in a cell array with the same numbers of a certain column of another cell array?

Tags: octave

I have a cell array that has the size of 4x1, but it can vary depending on the data input.

Each cell is a matrix with 10 columns and again depending on the input around 10000 to 70000 rows, all containing numbers.

Additionally I have another cell (again several cells containing many rows, one column) array that holds the unique values of the column 6 of each of the cells of the big cell array (column 6 contains `pointnumbers` of measure points, there are many timestamps of the same `pointnumber`).

I now want to go through each cell of the first cell array and group all the different timestamps of each unique `pointnumber` into one cell and therefore create a new cell array.

How to extract the rows of cells in a cell array with the same numbers of a certain column of another cell array?

I have tried a few versions of the for loop down below, but there are always errors (no matching dimensions etc) or it only returns the first cell.

```
    for i = 1:N
      a = C1{i,1}(:,6) == inter_igp{i,1}(i,1);
      C1_new{i,1} = a;
    endfor
```

C1 is the big cell array, of which I want to look into each cell into column 6 of the matrix and put every timestamp of the points which are in `inter_igp` cell array grouped into a cell into the new cell array `C1_new`.

The Cell Arrays mentioned have the following sizes (notice, the amount of rows changes as the data input changes, the amount of columns stays the same.

```
    C1 = {{rand(10,10)} ; {rand(30,10)} ; {rand(20,10)}};

    inter_igp = {{rand(10,1)} ; {rand(15,1)}};
```

I now want to know which rows in each cell of `C1` in column match every value of inter_igp (now of course random matrices will not match but this is only to show the size of the cell arrays) and then put all rows belonging to the same value of `inter_igp` in a sperate cell in `C1_new`.

Comment: This question is not clear to me. Could you add an example `inter_igp` and `C1` into your question? I think showing a small example data set is a better way of communicating than trying to explain what it looks like. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I hope the matrices I added show the kind of data I want to handle, these of course are random, my data is not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First of all your input data:

```matlab
C1 = {{rand(10,10)} ; {rand(30,10)} ; {rand(20,10)}};
```

You are here creating a cell array with cell arrays, and each of these inner cell arrays has just a single element. Consequently, to access the matrices stored, you need to do

```matlab
C1{ii}{1}
```

That `{1}` is totally superfluous. Instead, create your cell array as follows:

```matlab
C1 = {rand(10,10) ; rand(30,10) ; rand(20,10)};
```

or equivalently:

```matlab
C1 = [{rand(10,10)} ; {rand(30,10)} ; {rand(20,10)}];
```

In the first case we made a cell array containing 3 arrays. In the second case we made 3 cell arrays, each containing 1 array, and then concatenated them into a single cell array with 3 arrays.

The same is true for the second input array.

---

The second issue is the equality sign. If we're comparing floating-point values (as returned by `rand` in the example data) then we'll be highly unlikely to find any two equal elements. If this is the true case, compare with a tolerance. However, since in the real problem these are time stamps, it likely is OK to compare with equality.

However, comparing two different arrays this way will not work. `A==B` compares each corresponding pair of elements, `A(ii)==B(ii)` for all `ii`. This is not the logic we're after. We're looking for all elements in the first array that are also in the second array. This can be solved with `ismember`: `ismember(A,B)`.

---

The third issue is that you're indexing with `i` into `inter_igp`, but `i` is an index into `C1`, and these two arrays are not the same size. I assume you want to find, for each array in `C1`, one array that matches each of the elements in `inter_igp`. This would lead to a two-dimensional output array: `C1_new{ii,jj}` would be the elements from `C1{ii}` that have time stamps matching `inter_igp{jj}`.

---

Understanding all these things above (and assuming I understood correctly the problem), the correct code would be:

```matlab
C1 = {randi(50,10,10) ; randi(50,30,10) ; randi(50,20,10)};
inter_igp = {randi(50,10,1) ; randi(50,15,1)};

C1_new = cell(numel(C1), numel(inter_igp));
for ii = 1:numel(C1)
   for jj = 1:numel(inter_igp)
      index = ismember(C1{ii}(:,6), inter_igp{jj});
      C1_new{ii,jj} = C1{ii}(index,:);
   end
end
```

Note that I used `randi`, which outputs integers. This allows me to do equality comparison.

Note also that I'm preallocating `C1_new` to avoid resizing it with every loop iteration.